# What is the difference between these two tensorflow variables (or tensor): kernel:0 and kernel/Adam:0

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, tensor

I'm working on Tensorflow recently.

I have a trained model, and need to check the variables in it.
So, I've restored the graph from the meta file, and obtained the variables by:

```
gvars = tf.global_variables()
```

I'm interested in the kernels of each convolution layers, and they got names like `'.../kernel:0'`. However, I found a similar tensor named `'.../kernel/Adam:0'` but having totally different values!! What I only understand is that the `.../Adam:0'` things are related to the training (optimization) processes, but, not sure...

So.. what is the difference between two, and which one is actually used in evaluating, testing, deploying, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam keeps per parameter [statistics for its update](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf), see Alg. 1.
In TensorFlow these are [generated here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6da31773d5d6aecb5672da6024bd03fc803ee599/tensorflow/contrib/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L926) and [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6da31773d5d6aecb5672da6024bd03fc803ee599/tensorflow/contrib/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L115-L118).

For inference, you just need to rely on `.../kernel:0`.

Comment: Thanks :) it helped!